# Save and Retrieve Image File From Realm

Tags: ios, filesystems, realm, realm-mobile-platform, save-image

Writing to the file system allows users to write and retrieve string, image, etc., files to and from the application on their devices.

The images I write and retrieve to the app that appear when I run the simulator, for example, are unique to that app bundle, and differ from the images I write and retrieve from my device.

When I research how to write and read image files with Realm I am told not to save the image but the path. Images are too large to store. Got it.

But the file path I am saving naturally returns data native to the specific app bundle-- or returns nil. How might I write and retrieve image files/paths to and from Realm if the file path is unique to the device(s)? Do I need a separate image array?

**First View Controller**

```
let planet = planets[indexPath.item]
cell.name.text = planet.name
cell.system.text = planet.system

  let imageData = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("image")
        if self.fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imageData) {

            // Populates every cell with the same image

            cell.earthImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageData)    

            // returns nil

            cell.earthImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: planet.image)
        } 

 // Retrieve directory path for image

func getDirectoryPath() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

**Second View Controller**

```
  let planet = Planet()
        self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: config(user: SyncUser.current!))
        planet.name = self.name.text!
        planet.system = self.system.text!

  let imageData = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("person")
        if self.fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imageData) {
            self.earthImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageData)

            // Why does this not write to realm?

            planet.image = imageData
        }

        try! self.realm.write {
            self.realm.add(planet)
        }
```

Here, I am posting from the `secondViewController` where I would like to render these values in my `collectionView` in the `firstViewController`'s `numberOfItemsInSection_:)` method.

Here's the model:

```
class Planet: Object {
  @objc dynamic var name = String()
  @objc dynamic var system = String()
  @objc dynamic var image = String()
}
```

Comment: Why is the file path unique to the device? I looks like the data is stored in the documents directory and as long as the document you are loading is called *person* your code works (It works for me). However, the filename is something more like probably *person.png*. Can you be more specific as to the issue? Is the planet.image = imageData code executing? Did you add a breakpoint to see if the code gets to that line?

Comment: Yes. The issue is I am trying to write the value of the selected image from my `imagePicker` to realm. In my second VC, I can write `name` and `system` to realm as unique values, so that in first VC they are unique to each cell. This simple because they are both text Types.

Comment: But returning the value from the documents directory populates all the image objects in the cell with the same image, which makes sense. If I change the image in `imagePicker`, that new image will populate all the cells with the same image. The goal is for every cell to have a unique image according to how they are saved in second VC, which ideally would look something like `planet.image = earthImage.image`. Obviously this raises an exception as `earthImage` is an image.

Comment: It's still very unclear what you are asking. If you have a Planet object, it will have name and path. The name is the name of the planet and path is a path to where it's stored on the drive. In the case of our solar system Realm would have 9 (errrr.. 8) planet objects and each object would contain a path to the image. When you load up your Realm, iterate over the objects and populate your imageViews accordingly. If Pluto was magically reinstated, it would be added onto Realm as the 9th planet. Where is the issue in that process?

Comment: You cannot convert a `UIImage` into a `String`. So `earthImage : UIImage`, and `planet.image`, an instance of the `Planet` object that has a property `image`, are incompatible. Look at the code, again. The `name` property of the `planet` instance is easily set to the `name` textField because both are `Strings`. Images must be converted into data. I use a `String` type to access my image because I find it easier to use with the `Data` type. The point remains, my `earthImage : UIImage` cannot be saved into Realm, only the path. How do I save the path?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting converting an image to a string. I assumed that planet.image was the path (a string) to the actual *image* file stored on the drive - perhaps in the documents folder (see my prior comment). Your path is a string so store it as a string in realm (Or if its a URL, then URL.path). May I am not understanding the question but the path is (can be) a string so handle it as such.

Comment: This does not work: `try! self.realm.write { self.realm.add(planet) }` Also,  remember, I am using a `UIImage` and a `collectionView`. I need to convert the string from the path into an image, as my `collectionView` is an array of planet instance objects, e.g.; `cell.example.text = planet.example`.

Comment: Obviously I cannot do this `cell.earthImage = planet.image` because the image on the `planet` instance is a string. What is the code to save and retrieve an image in realm using a `collectionView`? That is my question.

Comment: I think maybe there is a terminology issue here. PATH is the location of the file on the drive  /users/some_user/documents/earth.jog. That is a string and provides a direction/locations of where the earth.jpg file is stored on the drive (can also be a URL). If you are trying to convert an image to a string to store in a database, one option is to use base64EncodedString along with NSData and NSImage. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666269/firebase-query-with-variables-in-swift/35672849#35672849). It's Firebase but the decoding part is the same.

Comment: The other issue is that the question in your comment is opposite of what you first asked. Your original question says *I am told not to save the image but the path. Images are too large to store. Got it.*. So my comments address how to get and save the path. Now you are asking how to store the image itself in Realm. which is a different question. Perhaps updating your question to be more clear would then help us to provide a solution.

Comment: I don't understand where we are in this discussion: if you know how to do this, please submit a code example. I can convert an image to a string and back. That is not the issue. Saving and retrieving this path to a realm, in a `UICollectionView`, is the issue. That's it.

Comment: I am sure I know how to do it, but I still don't understand the question. If you know how to convert an image to a string and back, then a *path* is not relevant. i.e. once and object/image is in memory then it wouldn't have a path to a file on disk as at that point it's in memory. Also, as I stated above, a path is a string. For example; *let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/documents/test.jpg")* and then *print(url.path!)* will print */documents/test.jpg*, a string. Paths are always strings so again, the question is unclear.

Comment: How do I save this in my realm? That is the question. What is the code above in `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` doing wrong, and what is the code solution (or sample) for it?